What's the next step to improve my Milky Way photography?
For the first time, I took Milky Way pictures last night with a Canon 18-55mm lens, ISO 6400, f/4, 30sec. I took 10 light and 10 dark pictures, then stacked them in DeepSkyStacker. It turned out as shown below.
Why did I get so many stars? The picture quality is also not good. What's my next step to improve the quality and reduce the stars?


Given that the stars really are there, why do you think you have "too many stars"?

great start actually, next is find somewhere to shoot that has no, if possible, light pollution.

I don't think the picture has enough stars. What do you actually see on a clear night, away from urban light pollution?

Related: Capturing the Milky Way: what did I do wrong? and How to have colors in Milky-way? and How to capture more stars? What all three have in common is that the answers emphasize that you must have very dark skies to capture anything resembling a good Milky Way photo. No light pollution and the moon below the horizon.

Thank you all for helping me out here, next time i will consider all your thoughts in my photography.
